PhpStorm plugin requires com.jetbrains.php to be installed, yet is not selectable - how to resolve?
I use PhpStorm 2024.2.3. I use a remote setup, my local PhpStorm connects to SSH to a remote PhpStorm session.
I have the plugin "PHP Annoations" installed. After a restart, an error message popped up "Requires plugin 'com.jetbrains.php' to be installed":

This wasn't required before, and I never had to do anything special to run this plugin.

Update: After a further reboot, all my plugins were removed.
